# How do i split a file into small files each time i encounter the value '20' in 9 and 10 columns

Tags: linux, files

for ex:
This is the source file. 20 is present in 9 and 10 columns in row '1' and '9'. So i need to split it into 2 chunk files as file 1 and file 2 (as i have encountered the value 20 in column 9 and 10 twice).

```
0012345020DTL0
00000000510000
00000000520000   
00000000530000                                                                                                                                                                                                 
12342000510000
00000000520000  
00000000532000
00000000800000
0000000020DTL0                                                                                                                                                                                           
00000000510730
00000000520000
1234500053 000                                                                                                                                                                                                   
00000000510000
00000000520000 
00000000530000
00000000800000
```

Now i need to split the above file into chunk files based on the value `20` present in 9 and 10 columns. Whenever 20 appears in 9 and 10 columns only split the file into multiple chunk files. If 20 appears anywhere else other than 9 and 10 columns i do not have to split it.

Output:file 1:

```
0012345020DTL0
00000000510000
00000000520000   
00000000530000                                                                                                                                                                                                 
12342000510000
00000000520000  
00000000532000
00000000800000
```

file2:

```
1298600020DTL0                                                                                                                                                                                           
00000000510730
00000000520000
1234500053 000                                                                                                                                                                                                   
00000000510000
00000000520000 
00000000530000
00000000800000
```

Comment: hould your example files have two columns on some lines or is that a formatting error?

Comment: Why is `0000000020DTL0` present in both files? How exactly do you need to split? You say "based on the value 20 present in 9 and 10 columns", but what does that mean? Do you want all lines with that value in the same file? Do you want to start writing to a new file each time that value is encountered? Please [edit] your question and describe what you need more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `csplit` for pattern-based file splitting:

```
csplit <file> <split pattern> <repetiotions>
```

I.e.:

```
csplit -z datafile '/^........20/' '{*}'
```

Explanation:

- `-z` : do not create empty file (as you start with the pattern in the first line, there would be a file from "0th" line to the pattern match
- `'/^........20/'` : The pattern to match for splitting, where `^` = beginning of line, `.` = any character (8 times)
- `{*}` : repeat as often as possible

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{filename=0};$0 ~ /^........20....$/{filename++};{print >> "file"filename}' input_file
```

With the provided input this would produce:

`file1`:

```
0000000020DTL0
00000000510000
00000000520000   
00000000530000
00000000510000
00000000520000  
00000000530000
00000000800000
```

`file2`:

```
0000000020DTL0
00000000510730
00000000520000
0000000053 000
00000000510000
00000000520000 
00000000530000
00000000800000
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)